# What is the difference between having separated Ubuntu or having Ubuntu on windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows, windows-10, microsoft

Okay, so Microsoft is currently doing some dope with windows 10.
The new terminal and now it supports Ubuntu. I don't know in what way how this will affect me. We now have Several versions of Ubuntu on Windows store that we can download. And the new terminal support Ubuntu command lines.

I want to know how this will affect people( like me ) who uses dual boot systems and do most of there development in Ubuntu.
Having all these new features can help me do all the things on Windows?
If yes, should I completely move to Windows?
If not, then what exactly MS is trying to do?

Comment: PS: from 'having ubuntu on windows 10' i didn't mean using VM's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two versions of the WSL (Windows Subsytem for Linux):

- The first version, released a while ago, is basically like the inverse of [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/), i.e. it translates Linux system calls into Windows system calls.
- The second version, just announced recently, does away with the translation layer and instead ships an actual Linux kernel that runs alongside the Windows kernel. This does two things:

  1. increases speed since system calls no longer need to be translated and
  2. increases compatibility, again because the system calls no longer need to be interpreted.

What Microsoft is trying to do is convince developers to develop on Windows instead of Linux since they can be right at home with all their favorite Linux development tools.

Whether you still need to dual boot or not is dependent on your use case. If you don't want Windows Update announcing that it will be rebooting you in 15 minutes to install updates, then you probably want to stay with your dual boot :)

Comment: I do web development mostly and recently started with DevOps. So I guess apart from having issues with updates( which I can change in settings), I should shift from ubuntu to win 10

Comment: @SIDDHARTHVARSHNEY I mean it really comes down to personal preference. I for one despise Win10

Comment: Switch aftre making sure that you can run Linux docker images in the Win10+Linux combo.